# append list values to array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a list value like this

```
t=[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]
```

and I declare empty array

```
earr=np.array([])
```

so I would like to have an array like this

```
earr=array([1,2],
           [3,4],
           [5,6])
```

so I used this line to try to concatenate the list to the empty array

```
for i in range(len(t)):
    earr = numpy.append(earr,[t[i]])
```

but the output of this array like this `array([1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6.])` how can I make it like the output in the top?

Comment: Is `np.array(t)` what you want?

Comment: ya wow I feel stupid right now thank you

Comment: No worries. Always go for a quick search on SO before posting. This one was easy to find

Comment: okay i will :D thank you